# how to add more variant in matrial ui typography

Tags: material-ui

in the design I'm styling I have more then style for the Heading

1. h1 with Serif typo
2. h1 with San Serif Typo

Is anyway to have more then variant for the same H tag name!? to add it to `createMuiTheme`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwrite style of [`<Typography>`](https://material-ui.com/components/typography/) component, and then use h1 variant:

```
import React from "react";

import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const SerifTypography = withStyles({ root: { fontFamily: "serif" } })(
  Typography
);
const SansSerifTypography = withStyles({ root: { fontFamily: "sans-serif" } })(
  Typography
);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <SerifTypography variant="h1">Serif</SerifTypography>
      <SansSerifTypography variant="h1">Sans Serif</SansSerifTypography>
    </>
  );
}
```

Live demo:

[image: Edit mutable-dawn-c2bqz]